# Adding all images to the Package.AppXManifest results in a compiler warning

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro, compiler-warnings

I have specified `win8_logo_small.png` for the "Small logo" in the `Package.appxmanifest` setting of my Windows 8 Store project. When I create a store package, I get this warning:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1052,9):
warning APPX1621: A mixture of images matching logical name 'win8_logo_small.png' exists
in this project with and without the "scale" or "targetsize" qualifier specified.
For predictable runtime behavior, explicitly specify the scale or target size
in each image asset's file name.
```

Although this is a mere warning, I'd like to know what Microsoft wants me to do about it because the names for the image scale variants are auto-generated:

```
win8_logo_small.scale-80.png
win8_logo_small.scale-100.png
...
win8_logo_small.targetsize-16.png
win8_logo_small.targetsize-32.png
```

If I rename the `xxx.targetsize` files to something like `xxx.scale-###.png` and add it to the project, Visual Studio automatically copies the file to a `xxx.targetsize-##.png`!

Is this something that can be solved? Does it need solving or is it just a bug in the Windows RT package compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scale and targetsize images should be mutually exclusive.   From [How to name resources using qualifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965324%28v=win.10%29.aspx)

> The targetsize qualifier can specify resources at a particular size
>   (in pixels). It is primarily used to specify file type association
>   icons or protocol icons shown in the desktop Windows Explorer. This
>   qualifier is typically used for square images or icons and specifies
>   only a single image dimension. The system or app requesting the
>   resource (ResourceContext.QualifierValues) must explicitly specify a
>   targetsize. There is no default. **If you use the targetsize qualifier
>   on a resource, you should not use the scale qualifier.**

Visual Studio could be a bit more clear about this, agreed, since the app manifest UI implies you could/should supply all of them.

Comment: I will remove the .scale images for the small logo.