# Windows 10 Phone Store Logo Error

Tags: windows-phone, uwp, unity-game-engine

I created my app in Unity and after publishing for Android and iPhone, i'm trying to get the Windows 10 Phone version published.

I added my image assets to Unity, but when I open the generated project in Visual Studio, I get the following error in the Visual Assets tab:

A mixture of mages with and without the "scale" or "targetsize" qualifiers exists in the project for the logical name "Assets\StoreLogo.png" for the "Scale 100 50x50 px" image.  All the other images are importing correctly.

The only related question I see on SO is:

[Adding all images to the Package.AppXManifest results in a compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067357/adding-all-images-to-the-package-appxmanifest-results-in-a-compiler-warning)

but in my case it is an error instead of a warning

[image]

The image with the correct scale does exist in my Assets folder, even though I had to add it manually:

[image]

Just wondering if anyone knows how to debug/fix this? rename the image, create a new image etc?   ie: Why the 50x50px scale 100 image is not working as expected.

My Unity version is 5.3.4, Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically saying that `StoreLogo.png` will be ignored since there is a file with same name plus the scale qualifier: `StoreLogo.scale-100.png`.

When packaging the two files are considered the same, but to prevent unexpected behavior you should delete one of them. It basically means that if you change `StoreLogo.png`, but not `StoreLogo.scale-100.png`, the output will not change since the packaging process will always ignore the `StoreLogo.png` file.

I would rename the `StoreLogo.png` file to just `Logo.png` and keep them both. But you can also delete one of them and get rid of the warning.

Comment: Deleting StoreLogo.png fixed it.  It looks like the Unity export to VS created this file for me automatically for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the order of adding the PNG to the project matters.  So, for the StoreLogo you would need to add the 50x50 resolution PNG first.

And if you are using version control, make sure it is checked-in.